# How to detect php xdebug in shell script

Tags: php, shell, xdebug

Basically if php has xdebug installed I want to run tests with code coverage enabled. Otherwise just run the tests without code coverage. Something like this:

```
if [[ <detect xdebug> ]]; then coverage="--coverage-xml"; fi
vendor/bin/codecept run $coverage
```

It's easy to know if xdebug enabled using

```
php -v | grep Xdebug
```

If this command returns something xdebug is enabled, otherwise it's unavailable.

I just don't know how to use it in the if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if php -v | grep -q 'Xdebug'; then
  echo "Xdebug installed"
fi
```

Comment: I'm well aware of that function. However I need to detect it in shell script, not in php.

Comment: Is it possible to do it inside the if? I need it for .travis.yml so a one-liner would be better.

Comment: I didn't expect it to be so easy. Works perfectly, thanks!